# On modal window, Is it necessary to put the word "VIEW" ITEM in the title of the modal after clicking a VIEW ITEM button or in a dropdown?

Tags: modal, title, overlay, view

Example below is viewing a quote:

A - View quote as the title (quote number as part of the content)
[image]

B - Quote number as title and removed it from the content
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its not a mandate to have the word View in the modal. Every modal that opens need not have just view option, some might provide edit or other functions for the user. Showing the Quote number as in your second example should be fine. Keep the title with consistent format for other modals as well.

Find here a good read about the best practice for modal desgn fro UX Planet:
https://uxplanet.org/best-practices-for-modals-overlays-dialog-windows-c00c66cddd8c

Comment: Thanks @vinay based on your link provided: 

2. Descriptive Title
Give context to the user with the modal title. This allows the user to know where he/she is because they haven’t left the original page.

Does it really make sense to the users that they are actually VIEWING the quote? Also as you mentioned with Edit, means it really help the users understand that they are really in the Edit mode.

Other Example:
Edit Quote  - Edit Quote
Delete Quote - Delete Quote
View Quote - Quote No. 123456

Comment: @Sknny: I meant, if the only functionality on the modal is View and there is no other functionality like edit for the user, then it might be fine to just show title like 'Quote - 1234', but yes if they have other functional option like edit the quote then it would be good to show that on title like : 'Edit - Quote 12345'.